# java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present exception thrown when tried to check whether the emailID is registered or not in POSTGRES database

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am new to Spring boot, I have tried to check with unregistered emailID whether the given email id is available or not in the Postgres database. But unfortunately got this NoSuchElementException. I have attached an exception screenshot here for your reference. Can you guys help me to come out of this problem?.

**TipTopController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/user")
public class TipTopController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping(path = "/registration")
    public ResponseEntity<UserRegistrationResponse> registration(@RequestBody UserRegistrationModel userRegistrationModel){
        UserRegistrationResponse userRegistrationResponse = userService.doUserRegistration(userRegistrationModel);
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.set("description","User created successfully");
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
                .headers(httpHeaders)
                .body(userRegistrationResponse);
    }

}
```

**UserService.java**

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(UserService.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Transactional
    public UserRegistrationResponse doUserRegistration(UserRegistrationModel userRegistrationModel){
        UserRegistrationResponse userRegistrationResponse = new UserRegistrationResponse();
        try{
                logger.info("Entering into try block");
                Optional<UserInformationRepo> userInformationRepo=userRepository.findById(userRegistrationModel.getEmail());
                logger.info("Get value is "+userInformationRepo.get().getEmail());
                logger.info("Username is "+userInformationRepo.get().getFirstName()+" "+userInformationRepo.get().getLastName());
                if(userInformationRepo.isPresent()){
                    userRegistrationResponse.setStatus(false);
                    userRegistrationResponse.setMessage("This email id { "+userRegistrationModel.getEmail()+" } is taken by another user already");
                }
            else{
                    UserInformationRepo userInformationRepoSave = new UserInformationRepo();
                    userInformationRepoSave.setEmail(userRegistrationModel.getEmail());
                    userInformationRepoSave.setFirstName(userRegistrationModel.getFirstName());
                    userInformationRepoSave.setEmail(userRegistrationModel.getLastName());
                    userInformationRepoSave.setEmail(userRegistrationModel.getPassword());
                    userRepository.save(userInformationRepoSave);
                    userRegistrationResponse.setStatus(true);
                    userRegistrationResponse.setMessage("New user account created with your " + userRegistrationModel.getEmail() + " emailId");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            logger.error(e.getMessage()+"*****"+e);
            System.out.println("Exception occurred");
        }
        return userRegistrationResponse;
    }
}
```

**UserInformationRepo.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_INFORMATION")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserInformationRepo {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;
    @Column(name="FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name="LASTNAME")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name="PASSWORD")
    private String password;
}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserInformationRepo, String> {
}
```

This is the exception I got while tried to hit the registration API from POSTMAN tool

[image: Full StackTrace for your reference]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Are you sure that `com.ajithan.tiptop.tiptopapplication.domain.UserInformationRepo` is a correct [fully qualified class name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html)?
2. Are you sure that the entity `UserInformationRepo` has an appropriate constructor for this:

```
UserInformationRepo(UI.EMAIL,UI.FIRSTNAME,UI.LASTNAME,UI.PASSWORD)
```

3. You should not use a native query for this. You can use JPA query in this way:

```
@Transactional
@Query(value = "select new com.ajithan.tiptop.tiptopapplication.domain.UserInformationRepo(UI.email,UI.firstName,UI.lastName,UI.password) from UserInformationRepo UI where UI.email = :email")
UserInformationRepo checkUserExists(@Param("email") String email);
```

4. Why you can't just use the standard method?

```
Optional<UserInformationRepo> findById(String id);
```

You can avoid to use your custom methods `checkUserExists` and `saveNewUser` and start to use the standard `JpaRepository` methods `findById` and `save` in this way:

```java
@Transactional
public UserRegistrationResponse doUserRegistration(UserRegistrationModel userRegistrationModel)
{
   UserRegistrationResponse userRegistrationResponse = new UserRegistrationResponse(); // this was missed !!!
   try{
      logger.info("Entering into try block");
      Optional<UserInformationRepo> userInformationRepo = userRepository.findById(userRegistrationModel.getEmail());
      System.out.println(userInformationRepo.getEmail());
      if(userInformationRepo.isPresent()){
         userRegistrationResponse.setStatus(false);
         userRegistrationResponse.setMessage("This email id { "+userRegistrationModel.getEmail()+" } is taken by another user already");
         
      }
      else{
         UserInformationRepo userInfo = new UserInformationRepo();
         userInfo.setEmail(userRegistrationModel.getEmail());
         userInfo.setFirstName(userRegistrationModel.getFirstName())
         userInfo.setLastName(userRegistrationModel.getLastName());
         userInfo.setPassword(userRegistrationModel.getPassword());
         userRepository.save(userInfo);
         
         userRegistrationResponse.setStatus(true);
         userRegistrationResponse.setMessage("New user account created with your " + userRegistrationModel.getEmail() + " emailId");
      }
   }
   catch (Exception e){
      logger.error(e.getMessage()+"*****"+e);
      System.out.println("Exception occurred");
   }
   return userRegistrationResponse;
}
```

Comment: Could you please show your table `USER_INFORMATION` definition.

Comment: And by the way, why you do not use the standard `findById` method for checking existence?

Comment: The exception is resolved now by your JPA query way. But now when I am trying to hit the API with non-registered email id, its throwing null pointer exception.

Comment: I have tried the way which you proposed but now I got this exception (java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present) when tried to check with unregistered email id.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the full stacktrace.

Comment: I have modified the question and added the full stacktrace for your reference

Comment: Could you please remove the method `Optional<UserInformationRepo> findById(String email);` from the `UserRepository` interface and retry. It already declared in the `JpaRepository`.

Comment: Still not resolved even after removed the method **Optional<UserInformationRepo> findById(String email);** from the UserRepository

Comment: Please remove these lines: `logger.info("Get value is "+userInformationRepo.get().getEmail());
                logger.info("Username is "+userInformationRepo.get().getFirstName()+" "+userInformationRepo.get().getLastName());`

Comment: You should firstly check `userInformationRepo.isPresent()` and only if it returns `true` call the `userInformationRepo.get()` method

Comment: Now it's working fine...Thanks for your help @SternK